# ReIn-like framework for OpenCV+ROS+Python?

Tags: ros, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am working on using ROS + OpenCV via the cv_bridge package to process 2D video images using a sequence of filters.  One example is finding the Good Features to Track (GFTT) in a face by first doing face detection, then passing the returned bounding box as the ROI for GFTT.  Right now I am just combining these filters within a single node (Python script) but I was looking at the [rein](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rein) package/library and was wondering if something similar has or is been done for OpenCV and Python?

Thanks!

patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9958/rein-like-framework-for-opencv+ros+python?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2011-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your approach is completely appropriate.  rein should be considered no man's land and is unsupported at the moment.

---

Originally posted by [ethanrublee](https://answers.ros.org/users/200/ethanrublee/) with karma: 225 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-06-18**:
Sounds exactly what I was looking for.  I'll put my own work along those lines on hold until I see what you have developed.

**Comment by [ethanrublee](https://answers.ros.org/users/200/ethanrublee/) on 2011-06-18**:
We are working on an OpenCV + Python graph based modular vision framework, that will be released with docs in a couple of weeks.  Its more low level then "object recognition", but does enable higher level vision pipelines.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2011-06-18**:
Thanks for the response.  I've got a got a good start on a more modular vision framework similar to rein and will post back once I have something to show.